# How to dynamically set height of view based on its width by keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to have a view whose width is responsive to its container width while keeping its aspect ratio.
I don't want to hard code width or height, but keep it dynamic and responsive so that it can be reused in multiple situations as a reusable component.

I hope it works similar to the following code:

```
<View style={{
  alignSelf: 'stretch',
  aspectRatio: 1.5
}} />
```

It should fill its container's width and set its own height dynamically based on its width.

Is this possible in react-native with flexbox?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know **there is** `aspectRatio` style property in React Native! Such an effort-saver!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As Hendy Irawan commented, React Native added `aspectRatio` property to `StyleSheet`.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#aspectratio

From the document:

> aspectRatio?: number
>
> Aspect ratio control the size of the undefined dimension of a node.
>   Aspect ratio is a non-standard property only available in react native
>   and not CSS.
>
> On a node with a set width/height aspect ratio control the size of the
>   unset dimension On a node with a set flex basis aspect ratio controls
>   the size of the node in the cross axis if unset On a node with a
>   measure function aspect ratio works as though the measure function
>   measures the flex basis On a node with flex grow/shrink aspect ratio
>   controls the size of the node in the cross axis if unset Aspect ratio
>   takes min/max dimensions into account

Thus the following should work:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  view: {
    aspectRatio: 1.5,
  }
});

// later in render()
<View style={styles.view} />
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [Dimensions API](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html) to get the window's width, and then set height programatically. I typically call the dimensions as soon as the app loads, before you need to know the width, and then just pass the object around as needed.

This could be a custom component to accomplish your use case.

```
import {Dimensions} from 'react-native'

...

const AspectView = ({style, aspectRatio, children, ...props}) => {
  let {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
  return (
    <View style={[style, {height: width * aspectRatio}] {...props}>{children}</View>
  )
}
```

Comment: But this means it depends on the width of *window*, not the *container* (parent). How to set it based on the width of the parent?

Comment: I don't believe it works that way (unlike web css). The best bet is to programmatically calculate the parent and then pass it down.

Comment: I don't really get why that's not possible in mobile app. If the parent knows its width (whether fixed or calculated), why shouldn't the children be allowed to know its parent's width conveniently. `alignSelf="stretch"` is working wonderfully, so it should be possible to extend that a bit to allow the child to set an attribute based on parent's (instead of window's) width?